# What speed should have an alone planet to have a habitable zone due to relic radiation?

Tags: special-relativity, planets, cosmic-microwave-background, doppler-effect

What speed should have an alone planet to have a habitable zone due to relic radiation, without any star involvement?

How much time the planet will be able to remain in the habitable zone before the speed drops, given the planet has no engines?

Are such speeds achievable using gravity assist of the galactic center or similar objects?

What would be effect of non-CMB sources like particles and stellar radiation at such speed?

Comment: By speed, do you mean mean boosting a planet to blue-shift radiation up to something similar to what a star would provide?

Comment: @Brandon Enright  yes.

Comment: Check out [relativistic doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect).  I think a much more important question is, could the planet and atmosphere survive the non-light particles like electrons and interstellar gas if the CMB were shifted into visible light.  The answer is almost certainly "no" but I'd like to see the calculation.

Comment: @Brandon Enright I expanded the question.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad now.  "Gravity assist" uses orbiting bodies and steals a bit of energy from their orbit in the process.  There is no way an ordinary planet could withstand the gravitational tidal forces needed to slingshot it to relativistic speeds.

Comment: Er...you need Lorentz factors on order of 100-1000 (3ish K compared to 5800 K, fudged for solid angle). That is well into the ultra-relativistic regime. Actually with that much focusing you might need a factor *higher* than 5800/3. Yikes!

Comment: @dmckee I do not think 5800K is needed given that the shining surface will be much greater. At skies shining at 5800K the planet itself will become a star.

Comment: @Anixx remember though that the shift is dependent on the angle of the light so just assuming random orientation to the light direction the shift might need to be *even higher* to make the average light get shifted to near-visible ranges.

Comment: Anixx, That would be the "solid angle" consideration in my comments, but the Lorentz focusing at that kind of gamma is ferocious and could result in there being surprisingly little solid angle there.